# Using a variable as a css condition?

Tags: php, html, csv

I'm a beginner into programming, and I'm running into an issue.
As I'm browsing a .csv file in php, I'd like some of my variables to act as css conditions.

Let's say that my loop is like this:

```
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
print $line_of_text[0] . $line_of_text[1] . "<BR>";
}
```

And my .csv file is like this

```
paul, 10
george, 20,
john, 45,
ringo, 100,
```

How to make it so, for example, the numbers act as the font size? (So that paul would be written in 10px, george in 20px, etc...?)

Thanks everyone in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    print '<span style="font-size:' .$line_of_text[1].'px">' . $line_of_text[0] . $line_of_text[1] . "</span><BR>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For something like that you're better off with inline styles.  For example:

```
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    printf('<span style="font-size:%d">%s</span><br>',
            $line_of_text[1],
            htmlentities($line_of_text[0]));
}
```

Also noticed I'm using `htmlentities` to ensure that characters such as `<` and `&` that may appear in the CSV don't mess up your HTML output.